# Is it possible to design a switch circuit with XNOR's truth table value?

Tags: switches

[We all know XNOR's truth table right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate)? Is it possible to design a switch circuit (not a gate circuit) using XNOR's truth table value. I had tried for 40 mins and it seems impossible.

Switch Circuit Example:

image [image]

Comment: While the result may be ugly and unnecessarily complex and roundabout and inefficient, it should be possible by rewriting `S1 XNOR S2` as a combination of and, or and not (all of which are easily implemented via switches). Disclaimer: I have not actually tried this.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

In this position the lamp will be on. Switch A to the down position and the lamp will be off. Switch B to the down position and the lamp goes on again. So the lamp will be on if both switches are in the same position:

```
A     B     Lamp
up    up    on
up    down  off
down  up    off
down  down  on
```

This is equivalent to the XNOR's thruth table:

```
A     B     Y
0     0     1
0     1     0
1     0     0
1     1     1
```

To extend this circuit to more switches you need a "cross switch" (not sure about the name, in Dutch it's "kruisschakelaar"):

[image]

Changing the position of any switch will change the lamp's state, which is what you want if you want to control the lights in your living room from 2 or more points.

Comment: If one has some resistors and doesn't mind burning current in the idle state, one could produce a circuit with two SPST switches that would cause a light to turn on when one and only one was closed (though that would be xor rather than xnor unless one swaps the labels on one of the switches); the same approach would allow a light to be controlled by four SPDT switches, being turned on when an odd number are in the "left" position.  There was a puzzle in Radio Electronics ages ago on that subject, but the follow-up issue announced the puzzle was unsolvable with three SPDT switches.

Comment: Unfortunately, by the time I figured out that adding resistors (or series-wired light bulbs in a lightproof box) would allow a light to be switched on and off with four SPDT switches, Radio Electronics was out of business so I couldn't send in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SPDT switch:

```
      o-----o
----o/       \o----
      o-----o
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but has not been properly replied, I believe. The replies above first cheat a bit, as they use SPDT's, so the input's state does not depend on whether some current flows through the switch or not, but by coding its position. Second, because they do not fully comply with the truth table.

Yes, it is absolutely possible to reproduce any 2-input logic gate with a simple circuit, with only two single pole single throw switches (i.e. if current flows through the switch, then input is 1, if current does not flow through the switch, then input is 0), just one led and some resistors and diodes.

A rough design for a XNOR gate could be this one. (I'm only proving function, so, some refining can still be done to adjust current consumption):

Here is a [falstad example](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKAA8QUAWPCpL3BV5cQ2FCAAyAewDmASwDGAHQDOMgIYAXOivacuIsCl55C2cNggjuIABoA5APIAlAFyqAkgDNVAQVUuqgBCADSqmgAWdAB2qtFSmqoAwtCePirx0XSqUgBOqgBGCRFhKpExySwA7qJ4hsTiBrxgDaIsAG4gTSCENth1PTZUVFxUxFATMAgsKl08gyLd3VQQXuoANip0LGC9FK39IgitCMacIAAmdGsAruuaDOt0F%20CTULCsNd0t4jiE4AdqiA-gs5rxeiJsHouGZRGcuBhxthLF19CBfHoMAhzGJyBgSKJBNYREE9IQwOQYRAzOYYYs0UkgYdQcyflAWC8lvNjuJmeIrrd7jNgdh-t0QWyViA1ptti8Qd0ebVrJdruo7pogd1mVzeJAOftxKdeMausR-vy1RqDUrTYQEGLzecBeqhTUQQ6qCCIezcmDlf7JTR9X6FfMPYRhsGWH7dRR4U7aHAYz0HWb-mG9dGgA)

Comment: Why are SPDT switches a cheat, but active electronics aren't? You're making more assumptions with your circuit than with a simple switch setup.

Comment: As I explained, with SPST switch, the sole condition that defines the input status is whether current flows throw the switch or not. 

With SPDTs, you need to first agree on which position is 1, which is 0. 
On the other hand, in the examples shown above, I cannot see any case where the output is 1 -the led is lit- when no current flows through any of the two switches... And I'm using no transistors nor ICs. Just a couple diodes. So, replying to the first question, posted, it is possible.